# Changing label value in Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change a label value (lblRecipient) inside my Jquery dialog through a hiddenfield but somehow the label value is always empty, here I did a test by assigning a value '1234' and I can get the values in the alert box but the label value itself is empty. Please kindly advice.

```
function sendPMDialog() {

        $("#PMDialog").dialog('open');
        $("#PMDialog").scrollTop($("#PMDialog").scrollTop() - 1000);

        var Y =  document.getElementById('<%=lblRecipient.ClientID %>').innerText = '1234';
        alert(Y);
    }
```

Comment: *"...but the label value itself is empty..."* Labels don't have values, fields (like `input`, `textarea`, `select`, and `button`) have values. What do you really want? The inner text? The inner HTML?

Comment: As T.J has said labels don't have values. Use `.html();` instead of `innerText();`. Forgive me if I'm wrong but why use `document.getElementById();` when using jQuery? `alert($('lbRecipient.ClientID').HTML('New HTML'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing two assignments in one statement. Try breaking it down into one assignment per statement:

```
var label = document.getElementById('<%=lblRecipient.ClientID %>');

label.innerText = '1234';
alert(label.innerText);
```

or (using jQuery syntax):

```
var label = $('#<%=lblRecipient.ClientID %>');

label.text('1234');
alert(label.text());
```